# GTK prevent tab from focusing non-visible widget

Tags: gtk

I have several GtkExpanders along side some labels all inside of a GtkFlowBox. When tab is pressed focus cycles through the contents of the flow box. When focus reaches an expander then tab starts focusing the widgets inside the expander. The problem is this behavior occurs even if the expander is closed. Ideally if the expander is closed focus should shift to the next item in the flow box rather than the children of the expander but I'm not sure how to accomplish this. I suppose a more generic question is how do I prevent GTK from focusing something that is not visible?

Comment: See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/1898 and https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/2069

Comment: You can try [GtkRevealer](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRevealer.html), maybe works ok

Comment: To workaround you can connect to the notify::expanded signal and hide the children when expanded is false (I have not tested this)

Comment: I don't think a GtkRevealer will do what I want because it does not appear that I can have a widget on the actual widget itself. Something equivalent to `gtk_expander_set_label_widget()`. hiding/showing appears to work pretty well though